# How to find all the data that match a particular month from mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently having problem getting all the data from the database that match a particular month and show all the data from that month only. here's what I tried.

```
<?php 
require('./connect.php'); 

?>
<?php
$name1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM garden WHERE MONTH(Apr)");
$name1->execute();
 while($row = $name1->fetch()) {
    $t = $row["temp"];
    echo $t;
    echo "sdasds";
    }
    ?>
```

The database has `time` column that stores date as `12-Apr-2017` and I want to find all the details of april month or may month.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not using [`MONTH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) correctly. You need to pass the column identifier as the parameter and compare its value to the value you want which is 4 as April is the fourth month:

```
SELECT * FROM garden WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(dateColumn, '%e-%b-%Y')) = 4
```

If you want a more readable query use [`MONTHNAME()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname)

```
SELECT * FROM garden WHERE MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(dateColumn, '%e-%b-%Y')) = 'April'
```

You will also notice I use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) as you stored your dates as strings instead of dates. In the future you should consider storing dates as date values as converting them into a different format is easy and it makes doing date work a lot easier.

Comment: sorry about that but it still doesn't work btw my time field is in 'text' and stores all the date as 12-Apr-2017 format.

Comment: your answer is working john but how can i get only those columns that have value and not null I tried this SELECT temp FROM garden WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(time, '%e-%b-%Y')) = 4 AND temp IS NOT NULL but it still gives num of rows as 17 while it should show 18

Comment: That I can't say for certain without seeing the data but my best guess would be to change `%e-%b-%Y` to `%d-%b-%Y` as you may have leading zeros in your date that I was not accounting for.

Comment: ohh.. i fixed it. i was working on different database. but i want select only not null columns but above sql query isn't showing me that instead selects all of the rows. how can i do that?

Comment: That query shouldn't show rows with null values as NULL does not equal "April". But adding `AND time IS NOT NULL` to the end of the query should make sure null rows are ignored.

Comment: but temp is the column different than time that i don't want to consider whose some rows don't have values i.e. blank how will time is not null do that?

Comment: Sorry, just change `time` to `temp` and that should do the trick: `AND temp IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of providing Apr as parameter, pass 4 for april month. Then

Your query would look like
SELECT * FROM garden WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM time) = 4;

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks @rahulb but also, i want to get only those rows that have particular column filled in or not null how can i do that. can you help.

Comment: If you can paste your table values here it will be helpful for me to  look at